# React-native IOS MapView overlays does not display

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have a `MapView` for the IOS, overlays are not showing up on the map. Am I missing something here?

```
<MapView
  style={styles.map}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  followUserLocation={true}
  showsCompass={true}
  showsPointsOfInterest={true}
  annotations={this.state.annotations}
    overlays={[{
      coordinates:[
        {latitude: 32.47, longitude: -107.85},
        {latitude: 45.13, longitude: -94.48},
        {latitude: 39.27, longitude: -83.25},
        {latitude: 32.47, longitude: -107.85},
      ],
      strokeColor: '#f007',
      lineWidth: 3,
    }]}
/>
```

I took that `overlay` attribute from react-native example on facebook. I thought it was a problem with the map but my markers display just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this line `strokeColor: '#f007'` should be `strokeColor: ['#f007']`

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html#overlays

Comment: Thanks for that, but your A couple of months too late lol.  I completely forgot this was open.

Comment: Actually, it works for me with our without the `[ ]`.